# How to create a query function that will set a dynamic variable foreach selected column

Tags: django

Sorry if the title is misleading , i have a page that has many select option element , that will make you choose the database name , table name , column name , and filter .. here's the html

```
div class="row mt">
          <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="form-panel">
              <form class="form-horizontal  style-form" action="#">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="control-label col-md-3">Database Name</label>
                  <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="input-group bootstrap-timepicker">
                      <div class="btn-group">
                            <select id = "tableselect"  style="width:425px;background-color:white;height:30px;font-color:red;text-align-last:center;">   
                            <option disabled selected value>-- Choose --</option>                      
                            <!-- <li><a href="#"></a></li> -->
                            {% for table in obj2 %}
                                    <option value = "{{table}}" >{{ table }}</option>
                            {% endfor %}                          
                            <!-- <li><a href="#">Dropdown link</a></li> -->
                            </option>
                            </select>                    
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="control-label col-md-3">Table Name</label>
                  <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="input-group bootstrap-timepicker">
                       <div class="btn-group">
                            <select id="dataselect" style="width:425px;background-color:white;height:30px;font-color:red;text-align-last:center;">            
                            </select>                    
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group" id="column-name">
                  <button class="btn btn-theme" onclick="return appendBox()">Add</button>
                  <label class="control-label col-md-3">Column Name</label> 
                  <div class="col-md-4" id ="test">
                    <div class="input-group bootstrap-timepicker">
                       <div class="btn-group">
                            <select class = "columnselect" id="headerselect" style="width:425px;background-color:white;height:30px;font-color:red;text-align-last:center;">              
                            </select>                
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group" id="condition">
                  <button class="btn btn-theme" onclick=" return appendFilterBox()">Add</button>
                  <label class="control-label col-md-3">Filter</label>
                  <div class="col-md-4" id="filtbox">
                    <div class="input-group bootstrap-timepicker">
                       <div class="btn-group">                          
                            <select class = "columnselect" id="conditionselect" style="width:150px;background-color:white;height:30px;font-size:15px;text-align-last:center;"></select>
                            <select id="operator" style="width:120px;background-color:white;height:30px;font-size:15px;text-align-last:center;">  
                                <option disabled selected value>-- Choose --</option>            
                                <option> > </option>
                                <option> < </option>
                                <option> ≥ </option>
                                <option> ≤ </option>
                                <option> = </option>
                            </select>  
                            <input id="parameter" type="text" style="width:150px;background-color:white;height:30px;font-size:15px;text-align-last:center;">                                          
                            </input>                                                                 
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">                                                    
                  <div class="col-md-4" id="showquery">
                    <div class="input-group bootstrap-timepicker">
                       <div class="btn-group">             
                        <button id="result" class="btn btn-theme" type="submit" style="height:30px;width:100px;" onclick="return showQuery()">Show</button>

                        <button id="export" class="btn btn-theme" type="Export" style="height:30px;width:100px;" href="{% url 'polls:export' %}" onclick="return ExportFile()">Export</button>
                       </div>
                     </div>
                   </div>
                 </div>
             <div id="query_result">  
                        #Query result will be shown here
             </div>
<script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#result").click(function () {
        var urls = "{% url 'polls:load-query' %}";
        var table = $('#dataselect').val();

      data = {
        'name' : [],
        'table': table,
        'condition': []
      };

        $('#column-name .columnselect').each((idx, el) => data.name.push($(el).val()));
        $('#filtbox .input-group').each((idx, el) => {
          let column = $(el).find('#conditionselect').val();
          let operator = $(el).find('#operator').val();
          let value = $(el).find('#parameter').val();

          data.condition.push(`${column}${operator}${value}`);
        });

        data.name = data.name.join(',');
        data.condition = data.condition.join(' AND ');

        console.log(data);

        $.ajax({                     
          url: urls,
          data: data,
          success: function(data) {   
              $("#query_result").html(data);  
          },
          error: function(data)
          {
            alert("error occured");
          }
        });
      });
      });
  </script>

  <script>
      function appendBox()
      {
          $('#test').append('<select class ="columnselect" style="width:425px;background-color:white;height:30px;font-color:red;text-align-last:center;margin-top:5px"></select>')
            return false
      }
  </script>
```

For every option that can be choose , user can add another select option element for column name .

data name will be used for select in query , for example user choose user data name , so when we send the request , it will be like select [data_name](which mean user) from table_name where filter

here's the views

```
def list_all_table(request):
    data_name = request.GET.get('name',1)
    table_name = request.GET.get('table',1)
    column_name = request.GET.get('column',1)
    operator = request.GET.get('operator',1)
    condition = request.GET.get('condition',1)
    dsn_tns = cx_Oracle.makedsn('', '', sid='dicb') 
    conn = cx_Oracle.connect(user=r'', password='', dsn=dsn_tns) 
    c = conn.cursor() 
    c.execute("select "+data_name+" from "+table_name+" where "+column_name+operator+"'"+condition+"'")
    c.rowfactory = makeDictFactory(c)
    databasetable = []
    for rowDict in c:
        databasetable.append(rowDict['data_name'])

    context = {
        'obj2' : databasetable
    }
    return render(request,'define_segment.html',context)
```

for a single value , it is easy because my views no need to that dynamically and only need 1 variable to send the request . But what if user add more column name , how bout 2 ? how bout 3 ? we dont know really what user want to add how much .

I just want it to dynamically , if user add 3(for example , and value can change) column name, it will select 3 column and they can send 3 selected value to the return render(request,'define_segment.html',context). It's just i dont have in mind what i must suppose to do .

Comment: Do you already have the user input being sent to the view from the form?

Comment: @IainShelvington yes

Comment: Can you show an example of the input that you are getting?

Comment: @IainShelvington i already change the views in the question

Comment: @IainShelvington if its only 1 column name , it will return the same output like i want from the database . , the input is the same like in the select option value.. but if the user add more column name element, it will return 1

Comment: Have you tried `column_name = request.GET.getlist('column')`? If there are multiple values for the column input

Comment: @IainShelvington hmm never tried it before

Comment: @IainShelvington when i print the value of request.GET.getlist('column',1) , it will return 1

Comment: if  ```request.GET.getlist('column')``` it will return '[]'

Comment: Where are you defining the inputs with the name "column" that should be sending this data?

Comment: @IainShelvington in the ajax script -> ```$('#column-name .columnselect').each((idx, el) => data.name.push($(el).val()));```

Comment: `data` only sends 3 fields `name`, `table`, and `condition`. You are not sending any of the other fields that you are expecting

Comment: @IainShelvington  oh w8 mybad , i mean the data_name column , not the column_name , mybad i have a bad variablenaming

Comment: @IainShelvington  so i already have the input right , when i select ID and username , it will print as [ID,Username] , now how do i put the ID and username into the query ```c.execute("select "+data_name+" from "+table_name+" where "+column_name+operator+"'"+condition+"'")```

Comment: @IainShelvington i mean like , if the query succeeded to execute, i mean  i still need to prepare a dynamic variable to save the result like what i did in the views , ```databasetable = []
    for rowDict in c:
        databasetable.append(rowDict['data_name'])``` it will appliable for 1 column only *in my opinion*, if it is static like the user will choose 2 column every time, i will just make 2 variable

Comment: You should be able to have as many columns as you like. `databasetable.append([rowDict[column] for column in columns])`

Comment: @IainShelvington got error ```TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "list") to str```

Comment: What line is giving that error?

Comment: @IainShelvington ``` c.execute("select "+data_name+" from "+table_name+" where "+column_name+operator+"'"+condition+"'")```

Comment: getlist(data_name) make the result become list , i think i must find a way to make it not a list

Comment: Try `','.join(data_name)`

Comment: @IainShelvington yep already hehe , now i will try to execute the query and see what happen , i will let you know later

Comment: Okay, added an answer with an example template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So long as your column names list maintains its order you should be able to dynamically generate a table from the results

```
column_names = ['foo', 'bar', ...]
databasetable = []
for row in c:
    databasetable.append([row[column_name] for column_name in column_names])
```

Then return `databasetable` and `column_names` in the render context

```
return render(request,'template.html', {'data': databasetable, 'column_names': column_names})
```

Then in the template

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      {% for column_name in column_names %}
        <th>{{ column_name }}</th>
      {% endfor %}
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    {% for row in data %}
      <tr>
        {% for value in row %}
          <td>{{ value }}</td>
        {% endfor %}
      </tr>
    {% endfor %}
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: thankyou very much sir , i will try the example after this and i will let you know

Comment: line 181, in <genexpr>
   ```columnalldata.append(rowDict[data] for data in data_name)```
```KeyError: 'ID,USERNAME' ```

got error here sir

Comment: What is in `data_name`? Looks like you've got the column names joined?

Comment: ```data_name = request.GET.getlist('name')``` , its the column name that i mention before , sry for bad variable naming

Comment: but it suppose to be the same , because the only difference is the name of the variable

Comment: Seems like `name` is being passed as a single value with all column names joined by a comma. `data_names = request.GET.get('name', '').split(',')` then when you pass them to the query use `','.join(data_names)`

Comment: ah yes, it works now , thankyou so much sir , it really helpful for my project and thesis .. God Bless you sir